# Exception while evaluating EntityState of a List object in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I am building a small logging application. In few scenarios, I am saving one `TransactionHistory` object by evaluating the `EntityState`. When a new object is added to `DomainObject` (`TransactionHistory`), the entity state is changed to added and `SaveChanges()` works fine.

```
public void LogTransactionHistory()
{
     var transactionsHistory = new TransactionsHistory();

     transactionsHistory.TransactionId = 1123;
     transactionsHistory.Status = 2;
     transactionsHistory.Comments = "Single Entity";

     context.TransactionsHistory.Add(transactionsHistory);

     if (context.Entry(transactionsHistory).State == EntityState.Added)
     {
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

And while saving a list of `TransactionHistory` objects and evaluating the `EntityState`, I get this exception:

> The entity type 'List' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

This is my code:

```
public void LogHistoryList()
{
    var transactionHistoryList = new List<TransactionsHistory>();

    transactionHistoryList.Add(new TransactionsHistory()
            {
                TransactionId  = 50331,
                Status = 2,
                Comments = "Multiple entities",
            });

    context.TransactionsHistory.AddRange(transactionHistoryList );

    var addedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);

    // checking the entity state of transactionHistoryList
    if (context.Entry(transactionHistoryList).State == EntityState.Added) // exception
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class TransactionsHistory
{
    public long TransactionId { get; set; }
    public short? Status { get; set; }
    public string Comments {get ;set;}
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you get all `added` entities from `ChangeTracker` in `addedEntities` and don't need to check again in `if (context.Entry(transactionHistoryList).State == EntityState.Added)`.

`context.Entry` accept one `entity` but you pass the range of `entities` to `context.Entry`

You must change to this

```cs
context.TransactionsHistory.AddRange(transactionHistoryList);

var addedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Any(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);

if (addedEntities)
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Update**

if you want check all entities that are added, you can use this

```cs
foreach(var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    if(entity.State = EntityState.Added)
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do the savechanges by the above approach. But my question is why `if(context.Entry(transactionHistoryList).State == EntityState.Added)` is throwing exception.

Comment: @Vijay Because `Entry` method expects single entity instance, but you are passing list.

Comment: @Vijay Because `context.Entry(transactionHistoryList).State` get state of one `entity` and accept one `entity` in `Entry` method, but you pass a range of entities to `Entry` method